# Jekyll css not getting update

Tags: css, jekyll, jekyll-theme

I'm trying my hand in `Jekyll` and trying to build my first blog. I'm trying to customize the CSS of a basic theme as suggested in this [link](https://help.github.com/articles/customizing-css-and-html-in-your-jekyll-theme/)

It suggests to create a file `/assets/css/style.scss` and add the following:

```
---
---

@import "{{ site.theme }}";
```

I did the exact same thing and the CSS still won't update. I added this in the root folder exactly like below:

[image]

and style.scss have the following:

```
---
---

@import "{{ site.theme }}";

body{
    color:red;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does your rendered css look like?

Comment: It's still the default theme CSS ( i guess )